# Orchard - migrating site from iis 6 to iis 7.5 and the CSS/images/etc won't load

Tags: css, orchardcms

We migrated our websites from windows server 2003 to server 2008 r2 using iis 7.5.
Just simply coping the website folders to the new server,  setting the app pool to 4.0 integrated and using a Domain account to run the app pool I can get the site to come up.

that being said,  no images or the CSS seem to be working.  According to google developer tools it looks like it can't find it.

I've searched the net and really can't find anything exactly like this.  If anyone has any specifics I need to look for that would be great.  I'll attach my webconfig.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor"
        type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
            <remove name="host"/>
            <remove name="pages"/>
            <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false"/>
            <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false"/>
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false"/>
    </appSettings>
    <system.web.webPages.razor>
        <host factoryType="System.Web.Mvc.MvcWebRazorHostFactory, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <pages pageBaseType="Orchard.Mvc.ViewEngines.Razor.WebViewPage">
            <namespaces>
                <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc"/>
                <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax"/>
                <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html"/>
                <add namespace="System.Web.Routing"/>
                <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages"/>
                <add namespace="System.Linq"/>
                <add namespace="System.Collections.Generic"/>
                <add namespace="Orchard.Mvc.Html"/>
            </namespaces>
        </pages>
    </system.web.webPages.razor>
    <system.web>
        <httpHandlers>
            <!-- iis6 - for any request in this location, return via managed static file handler -->
            <add path="*/Theme.png" verb="*" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler"/>
            <add path="*/ThemeZonePreview.png" verb="*" type="System.Web.StaticFileHandler"/>
        </httpHandlers>
        <!--
        Enabling request validation in view pages would cause validation to occur
        after the input has already been processed by the controller. By default
        MVC performs request validation before a controller processes the input.
        To change this behavior apply the ValidateInputAttribute to a
        controller or action.
    -->
        <pages validateRequest="false" pageParserFilterType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewTypeParserFilter, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL" pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL" userControlBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl, System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL">
            <controls>
                <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL" namespace="System.Web.Mvc" tagPrefix="mvc"/>
            </controls>
        </pages>
        <compilation targetFramework="4.0" debug="true">
            <assemblies>
                <add assembly="System.Web.Abstractions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
                <add assembly="System.Web.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
                <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
                <add assembly="System.Web.Mvc, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
                <add assembly="System.Web.WebPages, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
            </assemblies>
        </compilation>
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
        <handlers accessPolicy="Script,Read">
            <!--
        iis7 - for any request to a file exists on disk, return it via native http module.
        accessPolicy 'Script' is to allow for a managed 404 page.
        -->
            <add name="ThemePreviewImage" path="*/Theme.png" verb="*" modules="StaticFileModule" preCondition="integratedMode" resourceType="File" requireAccess="Read"/>
            <add name="ThemeZonePreviewImage" path="*/ThemeZonePreview.png" verb="*" modules="StaticFileModule" preCondition="integratedMode" resourceType="File" requireAccess="Read"/>
        </handlers>
    </system.webServer>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="2.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Have you tried running the app pool in classic mode?

Comment: Are you sure the version of .net have been registered using regiis.exe?

Comment: What version of Orchard ? Can you paste web.config file you have in those static content folders ?